# For loop over telnet python

Tags: python, for-loop, telnet

I want to run a for loop over a telnet session; want to pass some commands to this system that is mostly test but the last value is a number (variable).

For the purpose of this post I posted with different text; but the gist remains the same; let's say I want to post `Hello World 1`, `Hello World 2` ... `Hello World n`.

I created a text file with multitude of `Hello World x` in a line by line like this. This was `hewo.txt`

```
Hello World 1
Hello World 2
.
.
Hello World n
```

This code worked:

```
tn = telnetlib.Telnet("x.x.x.x",23,5)
cmd_file = input(" Enter command file ")
selected_cmd_file = open(cmd_file,'r')
selected_cmd_file.seek(0)
for each_line in selected_cmd_file.readline():
     tn.write((each_line + "r" + "\n").encode('ascii'))
     tn.write(("\n").encode('ascii'))
```

But if it is as simple as calling the `tn` as object why could this not work:

```
for at in range(0,65): 
    tn.write(("Hello World" + at + "r" + "\n").encode('ascii'))
```

This for loop did not work.  What can be a possible solution?

Comment: I'd suggest getting the syntax right (missing `:`) and remembering that Python is **strongly** typed (you can't add integers to strings). An error traceback is more useful than *"did not work"*.

Comment: Jon i tried the suggestion yes silly mistake : . Now can you tell me if it is possible to send iterables over python telnet. What can i do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ,Jon i think i found the solution with this working loop. For anyone who is also interested please check this out. 

`for at in range(0,65): 
    tn.write(("Hello World" + str(at) + "r" + "\n").encode('ascii'))`

Comment: To concatenate string and integer just use str(at) to concatenate them....

Comment: Or `str.format`, or C-style `%` string formatting, or...